# Quickest Way to Read First Line from File

Tags: php, file

What's the quickest, easiest way to read the first line only from a file?  I know you can use `file`, but in my case there's no point in wasting the time loading the whole file.

Preferably a one-liner.

Comment: wonder if that's possible (read only the first line of a file without loading any "extras")

Comment: Maybe something like `$buffer = '';while(strpos($buffer, "\n")===false){$buffer .= fread($handle, 16);} $string = substr($buffer, 0, strpos($buffer, "\n"));`

Comment: `$line = (new SplFileObject($file))->fgets();`  —  Fancy construct-and-call-method syntax available as of PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$line = fgets($f);
fclose($f);
```

It's not one line, but if you made it one line you'd either be screwed for error checking, or be leaving resources open longer than you need them, so I'd say keep the multiple lines

### Edit

If you **ABSOLUTELY** know the file exists, you can use a one-liner:

```
$line = fgets(fopen($file, 'r'));
```

The reason is that PHP implements [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for resources.

That means that when the file handle goes out of scope (which happens immediately after the call to fgets in this case), it will be closed.

Comment: To avoid an unwanted `\n` you might want to add `trim()` to the one-liner.

Comment: Thank you very much for this Post and the explanation about the solution with one line and automatic file closing.

Answer (score 27):

```
$firstline=`head -n1 filename.txt`;
```

Comment: linux ftw.  I guess being the only 1 liner wasn't enough to get the answer vote... damn you microsoft!!

Comment: A one liner might be enough, but an answer that is totally newbie-unfriendly is not. The code might be fine, but if somebody needs this answer, he/she probably doesn't know PHP like his/her boots - I use PHP for 10 years and have no clue how/why your line works, and as such would never use it in my code. An explanation would be nice.

Comment: @Kalko, the backtick executes the string as a shell command in php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: @ssi-anik damn, I didn't know that. Thanks for the explanation. I suggest you add this explanation to the answer itself so more people will understand.

Comment: there are two problems with this approach:
1/ the question was about the quickest way, but the backtick operator means a serious overhead.
2/ if you use the "head" unix system command, your code will not be portable any more.

Comment: @ThatsMe "Serious overhead" in what way? Do you have benchmarks to explain how this approach is less performant than using the equivalent `shell_exec` function?

Answer (score 12):

I'm impressed no one mentioned the file() function:

```
$line = file($filename)[0];
```

or if version_compare(PHP_VERSION, "5.4.0") < 0:

```
$line = array_shift(file($filename));
```

Comment: _"I know you can use `file`, but in my case there's no point in wasting the time loading the whole file."_ :-)

Answer (score 8):

```
$line = '';
$file = 'data.txt';
if($f = fopen($file, 'r')){
  $line = fgets($f); // read until first newline
  fclose($f);
}
echo $line;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(file_exists($file)) {
    $line = fgets(fopen($file, 'r'));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In modern PHP using [`SplFileObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php);

```
$fileObject = new \SplFileObject('myfile');
$line = $fileObject->current();
```

---

*complementary information*

With `SplFileObject`, it's also easy to seek lines, for example to skip 2 lines;

```
$fileObject = new \SplFileObject('myfile');

$fileObject->seek(2);
$line = $fileObject->current();
```

or to read the first 10 lines;

```
$fileObject = new \SplFileObject('myfile');

$lines = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 10 && $fileObject->valid(); ++$i) {
    $lines .= $fileObject->getCurrentLine();
}
```

*note*: `getCurrentLine()` will read the current line and move the internal cursor to the next one (essentially `current()` + `next()`)

Comment: Is there any difference between `current()` and `getCurrentLine()`?

Comment: @matronator `getCurrentLine()` is an alias for `fgets()`; it's similar but it will move the cursor internally to the next line, essentially it is a current() + next(). I added a note.

Answer (score 1):

fgets() returns "
" which is a new line at the end,but using this code you will get first line without the lineBreak at the end :

```
$handle = @fopen($filePath, "r");
$text=fread($handle,filesize($filePath));
$lines=explode(PHP_EOL,$text);
$line = reset($lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to us [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) and declare the file size to read.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects (qSandbox) I uses this approach to get the first line of a text file that I read anyways.
I have my email templates are in a text files and the subject is in the first line.

```
$subj_regex = '#^\s*(.+)[\r\n]\s*#i';

// subject is the first line of the text file. Smart, eh?
if (preg_match($subj_regex, $buff, $matches)) {
    $subject = $matches[1];
    $buff = preg_replace($subj_regex, '', $buff); // rm subject from buff now.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind reading in the entire file, then a one-liner would be:

```
$first_line = array_shift(array_values(preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', file_get_contents($file_path), 2)));
```

:)

Comment: OP: *in my case there's no point in wasting the time loading the whole file*

Answer (score -9):

Try this:

```
$file = 'data.txt';
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete.

Comment: Provide complete Code