# Read from a textfile and put it in a array and display each line every 12 hour

Tags: php, arrays, text

So I have a website where I want to display a word from a textfile. 
I have done my textfile where the script should read from but it shows the whole textfile :S

```
<?

$filename = "arraytext.txt";
$arr = file($filename);
foreach($arr as $line){
    print $line . "<br />";
}

?>
```

`

It shows the whole textfile at once. I just want it to show 1 row and that's the first word.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `foreach` will loop through all the lines. Maybe you want to read [Quickest Way to Read First Line from File](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4521969/1983854)

Comment: $f = fopen($file, 'r');
$line = fgets($f);
fclose($f);

Will this only read one line?

Comment: It should. But test it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

To read file line by line, you have to use fgets() function
Here is an example :

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }

fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
  $filename = "arraytext.txt";
  $f = fopen($filename, 'r');
  echo fgets($f);
  fclose($f);
?>
```

To run it every 12 hours, add this line to your "/etc/crontab" file (for example):

```
00 11,23 * * * root php path-to-your-script/name-of-your-script.php
```

**UPDATE**: After your comment I think I better understood your question (sorry).
Forget about "crontab" stuff...
Just do:

```
<?
  $filename = "arraytext.txt";
  $arr = file($filename);
  foreach ($arr as $line) {
    print $line . "<br />";
    sleep(60 * 60 * 12); // (60 * 60) * 12 seconds sums up to 12 hours
  }
?>
```

Be warned, though, that php run in "web" mode (as opposed to "cli" mode) has strict execution time limits (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).
I suppose you are using this on the web interface since in your question you use the html tag `<br />`...

*Note: sorry, but **why** do you want to write one line each 12 hours??? :-)*

Comment: Awesome bro thank you.
It shows me the first row. How should I make it able to read the new line every 12 hour? It could be done with cron job right?

Comment: You don't need to say thank you, on SO. Just accept the most useful answer... :-)

Comment: So everytime this this runs it will automatically update to the next line?

Comment: The cron job didn't work. It doesn't change the text to the next line :S

Comment: Yeah I looked up foreach but now you wrote it. so the sleep will sleep everything until 12 hours has gone and then it will change line to the next one? Since my arraytext.txt is with <br> (this comment doesnt show it)for ex
First
Second
Third
etc

Comment: I have a site that shows the "daily" food. I want this to get updated every 12 hour so the "new" menu is out.

Comment: I see. This is not the right approach to address your use case, sorry... You really should read something about AJAX (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)...

Comment: Hmm. Shouldnt there be a way to create a script that reads the second line in the arraylist.txt? So it only jumps every 12 hour.