# How to get page <title> from content include into front controller

Tags: php, front-controller

I'm using a PHP based front controller pattern such that `index.php` provides the page structure and template, and all content for each page is in include files within `/pages/`.

```
index.php 
/pages/home.inc
/pages/about.inc
/pages/contact.inc
```

The include pages are mostly simple HTML so that clients can edit the pages without having to get into anything too complex.

The problem with this layout is that because all page information is in the page include, the `<title>` element can't get populated. I could put a `$title` variable in each include, but it loads after the head, which is too late:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>     #$title is not set yet!
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include($content); ?>              #now $title is set
  </body>
</html>
```

It's important that the content files are self contained and mostly HTML, but with the ability to have PHP code as well, as I mentioned, because customers will be modifying these and adding too much complexity is a problem. Thus, for example, setting up a separate database of page titles won't work because customers won't update the database when they make new pages.

**Edit:** a typical page include might look like this.

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>blah</p>
<?php include("nav.php"); ?>
<p>more blah</p>
<p>more blah</p>
<p>more blah</p>
<?php
  $pageJavascript = "alert('js!');";
  $pageTitle = "Cyberdyne Welcome Page";
?>
```

Comment: Are the .inc files all text? Or do they use variables as well?

Comment: They're HTML and PHP. Usually the PHP is just to include nav menus and such, but might be a small self-contained PHP script. They also do things like `<?php $pageJavascript = "function runAfterOtherJS(){demo}"; ?>` which gets `echo`'d in at the bottom of the page below all other JS is included.

Comment: I'm making the assumption that the moment you include it, it will do some output directly, content related. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, e.g. `<h1>Welcome</h1><?php include('nav.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Options:

## 1: Use output buffering

```
<?php
ob_start();
include($content);
$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo $body; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Pros**:

- The browser gets fully rendered page
- More SEO-friendly (than the javascript title update)
- No JS required

**Cons**:

- Need to buffer all the page in memory

## 2: Set some kind of general title and update it later with javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
with(document) {
  window.title = <?php echo json_encode($title); ?>;
}
</script>
```

**Pros**:

- You keep the same kind of flow You use now.

**Cons**:

- Not SEO friendly
- Requires javascript use

Answer (score 1):

If there is a assumption the title is always on the first line:
"My page Title";

```
$filename = '/pages/home.inc';
$fileLines = file($filename, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$title = yourFunctionThatStripsKomma($fileLines[0]);
```

Only bad thing is, is that you have to be sure the first line has the title.

Comment: Thanks. Just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521936/quickest-way-to-read-first-line-from-file) which shows a few other ways to grab just the first line. This is a decent option.