# Check if first line of file contains string

Tags: php, csv, pdo

I have a problem with PHP. I need to find out, if first row of .CSV file contains exact value. So far I tried:

```
$file = file_get_contents("./file.csv");
    if (strpos($file, "Value") !== false) {
        echo "Found";
    }
```

How to check, if first line of .CSV file contains text that says "Value"?

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php and then use index `0` or `1` (depending on if you have headings).

Comment: If the CSV is huge reading it all in with file_get_contents just to compare the first line isn't really efficient. [Check out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521936/quickest-way-to-read-first-line-from-file) some of these answers to see which method might be the best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue solved by looking exact places where I need to look :)**

```
if (strpos($data[0],'Value') !== false)
```